# What are the most promising non chemical rocket space launch approaches?

Tags: propulsion, advanced-propulsion

I read [this essay by Neal Stephenson](http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/future_tense/2011/02/space_stasis.html) recently, which makes the case that, had we not been locked-into chemical rocket technology through years of investments, other approaches might have been more viable.

As of today, what non-chemical rocket technologies appear to be the most promising for the future of space travel?

Comment: Related: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51/is-there-any-research-going-on-launching-into-orbit-with-space-guns-why-not

Comment: Nukes... (meaning NTR, of course, and more involved approaches).

Comment: I contest Stephenson's premise; we throw away huge investments in chemical rocket launch technology every single time we launch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There has been a lot of researching regarding Non-Chemical Rocket propulsion Systems.
The most recent one being [beamed thermal propulsion](http://www.space.com/7067-laser-propulsion-wild-idea-finally-shine.html). It involves propelling a rocket by using microwaves from the ground. 
[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-rocket_spacelaunch) you can find more Systems which have been researched on. Some have already been used, such as the Air Launch, where rockets are launched from conventional horizontal-takeoff aircraft, to carry satellites to low earth orbit.
Also some other examples are:
Static Structures: Space Elevators, Skyhook
Dynamic Structures: Space Fountain, Orbital Ring
And Mechanical Systems such as Pneumatic launchers.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-rocket_spacelaunch#Comparison) table gives the estimate build cost, the technological readiness for most of these Non-Rocket Space launch Methods.