# Launching multiple small satellites into orbit using magnets; is it possible?

Tags: launch, artificial-satellite

Is it possible to use magnets to launch small light weight satellites into a orbit around the earth to provide a net like coverage around the earth? 
Is it practical and will it be useful?

Comment: *"Launching multiple small satellites into orbit using magnets; is it possible?"*  Not any way I know.  But if you find a way to get objects to orbit using only magnets, you'll probably become a very rich person.

Comment: Related: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9156/what-would-make-a-rocket-sled-launch-feasible and http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2724/is-it-possible-to-literally-shoot-something-into-space/2728#2728

Answer (score 4):

Theoreticaly? Yes. There are papers about doing this either with a Coilgun or a train-like launch system (the (magnetic floating) "train" would accelerate along a miles-long track which at the end bends upwards).

But there are three very difficult problems to solve which make it rather unpractical:

1. Speed vs. drag: To reach a stable orbit you need a start-velocity of Orbitspeed (~8000 m/s) + Loss to gravity drag + loss to [drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29). The last one is the game-breaker: at ~15 km/s the air at the first few kilometres of atmosphere will be thick like a wall and will:

   a) kill most of your velocity really fast and
   b) create a lot of heat due to shock-heating.
2. Magnetic shielding: Your payload will be exposed to very strong magnetic fields while in your acceleration system. You either need a very robust satelite (like a simple brick of steel) or need to shield it somehow.
3. Accelaration: Since you need a huge starting-velocity, you need either really long tracks/barrels (like 100 miles long) or you need to accelerate at several 100s of Gs … Not a problem for a brick of steel, but your satellite will most likely be rather fragile.

Comment: The question is rather vague but it does mention orbit in the title. There's no practical way of doing that for _small satellites_ without any means of circularizing their final orbit.

Comment: True, as your "orbit" would go through your launchsite. You would need at least a small booster to increase your perigee to be over the atmosphere. (Solid fuel prefered since it is more likely to survive all those acceleration/decelarationforces)